# CORS Error and Unexpected Port After npm run build and npm start in MERN App

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, cors

I am developing a MERN stack application and facing two main issues. Firstly, despite configuring my application to run on port 5000 for production, it continues to run on port 3000 after executing npm run build and npm start. Secondly, I am encountering a CORS error when trying to communicate between my frontend and backend.

More Details:
Development Environment: During development, my backend Express server runs on port 5000, and the React dev server runs on port 3000, with no CORS issues due to proxy settings in the React app.
Production Issue:
After building the frontend and starting the app, it is unexpectedly served on http://localhost:3000 instead of http://localhost:5000.
I encounter CORS errors, specifically stating that the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is missing, even though I have configured CORS in my Express app.

What I've Tried:
Ensuring server.js is set to listen on process.env.PORT || 5000 and verified that my package.json scripts are correct.
Implemented CORS in my Express app using the cors package with a configuration that allows all origins in an attempt to resolve the CORS error.
Searched for any hardcoded references to port 3000 in my frontend that could interfere with the expected behavior.
Expected Behavior:
The entire application should be accessible from http://localhost:5000 in production.
There should be no CORS errors when the frontend makes requests to the backend.
Actual Behavior:
The app is served on http://localhost:3000, not on the expected port 5000.
CORS errors occur when attempting to make requests from the frontend to the backend, indicating a missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.
Questions:
How can I ensure that my MERN stack app correctly runs on port 5000 in production and resolves the CORS error for frontend-backend communication?
Is there a step in the build/start process or a specific configuration for handling CORS that I might be missing?

⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️

[MERN-Chat-App](https://github.com/HAck3R8/chat-app)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Express server listens on process.env.PORT || 5000, set PORT variable in production. Double-check frontend for port 3000 references. Review CORS middleware configuration, avoid * for origins.